# React Js - component parsing issue

Tags: jquery, reactjs

In reactjs I have 2 components, 1st component is giving me the value like

```
In DropDown.jsx : 

<div>1,2,3,4,5,6</div>
```

I'm rendering the value from 1st component and reading it in 2nd component as

```
import Options from './DropDown.jsx';
...
...
const Opts = <Options/>;
...
```

The above value is printing correctly if I print it inside `return()` method as it's in HTML format. But if I try to print outside return i.e :

```
render() {
    {Opts}
    return() {
      ....
      ....
    }
}
```

I'm getting output as

```
Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: Object, type: function…}
```

I want to split the div to array format. How can I read the value outside return method ?

Please let me know how can I handle this..

Comment: what do you mean about split the div to array? though i can say that your approach is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seems like a proper method. It is better to use an array instead. Maybe you can get the values from redux or a config file and pass it as props to `<Options name={array.key} value={array.value}>` component by mapping the array.